# visual profiler not working giving unable to profile application for non-zero return code

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, profiler

I wrote a multiple of code using CUDA and I profiled a lot before.

The code I am profiling now giving me a weird dialog box
unable to profile application.
"The application being profiled returned a non-zero return code"

The profiler is working fine for all the sample programs with the CUDA toolkit and my old programs. Also I tried an old program on the same file (by commenting my current code and copying one of the old files on the same source file) and surprisingly the profiler worked fine.

NB: The code is running fine with no errors while building or debugging.

It is difficult to attach the code here as it is 1200 line therefore I will attach the header files only

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include "cusparse.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mkl_lapacke.h"
#include "mkl.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <cuda_profiler_api.h>
```

the code is built using x64 bit project

Comment: The code is returning a nonzero error code. You have to fix that. It is not a profiler issue.Nobody can tell you why your code is returning a nonzero error code from just the headers.

Comment: @RobertCrovella What may be the error then ? The code is running correctly in command window! Also I have a question may it be from some lines out of the scope of cudaprofilerstart and stop??

Comment: The return code of the application is not the same thing as an error.  You need to learn what a return code is.

Comment: I found the problem... I am using a lapacke library in my code when I comment the commands related to the lapacke it worked well (I am using dgetrf and dgetri)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by commenting any command using the LAPACKE library. I don't know exact reason for that. But I preferred to tell you the reason